# Check if a circle is contained in another circle

Tags: class, python-3.x, methods, geometry

I'm trying to check if a circle is contained within another circle. I'm not  sure if the math behind it is the problem or if its my if statement because I keep getting `True` for anything I pass.

```
#Get_center returns (x,y)
#Get_radius returns radius length
def contains(self,circle):
    distance = round(math.sqrt((circle.get_center()[0]-self.get_center()[0])**2 + (circle.get_center()[1] - self.get_center()[1])**2))
    distance_2 = distance + circle.get_radius()
    if distance_2 > distance:
        return True        #Circle 2 is contained within circle 1
```

Comment: Do you mean thoroughly contained ? Or partially?

Comment: @CroCo The entire circle would have to be contained

Comment: dont you think self radius should enter the calculation?

Comment: @CroCo what do you mean by assumptions?

Comment: Well, your distance_2 is always distance + some positive number.   So checking if distance_2 is greater than distance, will always be true.  Well, you might get false if `circle` has radius 0.

Comment: Why `round()`? It introduces a small error into the calculation and can change the outcome.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't know about python but the math is simple. See the below picture

[image]

To check if circle 2 inside circle 1,

```
compute d 
    d = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 );
get c2 and c1
if c1 > ( d + c2 ) 
   circle 2 inside circle 1
else
   circle 2 not inside circle 1
```

Comment: Nice picture, makes answer obvious.

Comment: Good answer, just going to say you can do it without sqrt: ( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ) > ( d + c2 )^2

Answer (score 3):

You have `distance_2 = distance + circle.get_radius()`, so `distance_2` will always be higher than `distance` and `distance_2 > distance` will always be true.

Answer (score 3):

**CODE ACCORDING TO THE IMAGE IN THE ACCEPTED ANSWER** (without getters, as it's more readable):

```py
import math
def contains(self, circle):
  d = math.sqrt(
        (circle.center[0] - self.center[0]) ** 2 +
        (circle.center[1] - self.center[1]) ** 2)
  return self.radius  > (d + circle.radius)
```

I used it, and it works. In the following plot, you can see how the **circles *completely* contained in the red big one are painted in green**, and the others in black:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want strict containment, that means that the absolute value of the difference of radii will be less than the distance between centers.  You can exploit that in order to avoid taking square root (because squares of two positive numbers will have the same order as the numbers themselves):

```
def contains(self,circle):
    distance_squared = (circle.get_center()[0]-self.get_center()[0])**2 + (circle.get_center()[1] - self.get_center()[1])**2
    difference_squared = (self.get_radius() - circle.get_radius())**2
    return (difference_squared < distance_squared) and (self.get_radius() > circle.get_radius())
```

Btw, just as a style note, there is no need to write getters and setters in Python.  You can just have fields and if you need to modify how they are accessed, you can override it later on (without effecting any of the classes which access them).

Making this easy from the earliest versions (maybe even from the start) was one of the reasons Python was so appealing and managed to take off.  Python code tends to be very short because of this.  So you don't lose sight of the forest for the trees.