# Circle in circle collision

Tags: collision, geometry

How to find a collision between two circles if one circle inside another circle.
As the screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXxoJ.png)
Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490334/check-if-a-circle-is-contained-in-another-circle/33490701#33490701

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between the centers of the two circles is equal to the radius of the big circle minus the radius of the small circle, then they are colliding.

Comment: like this?
sqrt((x2 − x1)^2 + (y2 − y1)^2)  <= (r2 - r1)

Comment: @agaaliev Yes, but less than or equal no, only equal, because you want to know when the two circles touch each other in the circunference, I guess.