# capture and save image in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

```
import cv2
import face_recognition


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


face_locations = []

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()


    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]


    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)


    for top, right, bottom, left in face_locations:



        cv2.circle(frame,(int((left + right) / 2), top),15,(0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.circle(frame,(350 ,  150),5,(0, 255, 0), 1)



    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(25) == 13:
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Screenshot of the result : 
[image]

**Goal:**

**I need the save the image only if the green circle is inside the red circle and the saved image should not contain the circles.**

**If the green circle is not inside the red circle, it must not save the image.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the answer to this question as the basis:[Check if circle inside circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490334/check-if-a-circle-is-contained-in-another-circle)

x1, y1 -> Position of red circle

x2, y2 -> Position of green circle

c1 -> radius of red circle

c2 -> radius of green circle

```
import math
```

And after importing then you need to change the following

```
#frame without circles
frameToSave = frame

#add circles to frame in live feed
cv2.circle(frame,(int((left + right) / 2), top),15,(0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.circle(frame,(350 ,  150),5,(0, 255, 0), 1)

x1 = int((left + right) / 2)
y1 = top
c1 = 15

x2 = 350
y2 = 150
c2 = 5

d = math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))

if c1 > ( d + c2 ):
    print("green circle inside red circle")
    cv2.imwrite(filename,frameToSave)
else:
    print("green circle not inside or not fully inside red circle")
    cv2.imwrite(filename,frameToSave)
```

Edited a bit to fulfill the goal in the comments (live feed with circles, saved image without circles)

Comment: Commenting those lines would not show the circles in the live feed ( webcam video). I need those circles in the live feed but not when saving the image to a file. i.e The saved image must just be a picture of the face it the condition is met.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. Do you have it already or do you want the solution with the live feed with the circles and the extra frame without the cricles?

Comment: I actually need those circles during the live feed but when I save them using cv2.imwrite(filename,frame) I need the image without those circles.